# Is there a way to pass the --disable-stack-for-recursion option for PCRE when building POCO 1.11.7?

Tags: poco-libraries

Is there a way to pass the --disable-stack-for-recursion option for PCRE when building POCO 1.11.7?

I looked at the POCO source code for PCRE. It is under the Foundation folder. However, I do NOT see any option enable/pass the --disable-stack-for-recursion.